# Android clickable layout

Tags: android, android-layout, event-handling, click

I've got a linear layout that i have set true to be clikable + focus, But the problem is there is no focus displayed when clicked. How can i get the focus to be displayed.

Heres my code

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linear_tv_layout"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:paddingBottom="7px">
```

Comment: What kind of focus do you want to display? I don't think a linearlayout shows anything when it gets focused.

Comment: I just want after one touches the layout on screen it to highlight just like a button would indicate it has been clicked

Comment: if somebody wants to get full solution, check this repository: https://github.com/shamanland/AndroidLayoutSelector there is custom clickable/checkable ```LinearLayout``` like a ```ToggleButton```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you need to set as background  for the clickable view (the layout) a [state list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) , it's a drawable resource for which you can specify different drawables for different states or combinations of states, there's one for selection, one for pression and so on. Also, the state of a layout propagates to all its children.

---

CLARIFICATIONS - this is the example from the previously linked docs:

`res/drawable/button.xml :` (it's the state list drawable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

`button_pressed`, `button_focused` and `button_normal` are normal drawables representing the button in those states, probably png's (so pressed could be inset, focused highlighted in orange).

if you set this resource as background to your "linear layout button":

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

now focusing the layout will automatically set its background image to `@drawable/button_focused`, and so on.

of course, all the drawables you use must already be resources in `res/drawable/`, together with `button.xml`.

Comment: im a bit confused with the state list, would i have to change all the linear layouts i have used or is it just for the ones i choose

Comment: @M2Gd you choose which linear layouts will work like buttons by setting on them your state list drawable as a background.

Comment: i dont really understand what the state list drawable is, im new to android... i just want the background colour to change when the state pressed is true

Comment: @M2Gd i added some explanations - oh, the drawables for each state can also be just colors, like: android:drawable="#FF4422" - see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

Comment: i tried that and got error messages in that tab. This is my xml 
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:background="#313CDD" /> <item android:state_focused="true" android:background="#313CDD" /> </selector> thanks in advance

Comment: @M2Gd when you define the state list drawable you must respect the format. you have to put android:drawable, not background. android:background is for the layout.

Comment: [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30186838/1255482) by @jennifer-wang will apply the default material style.

Answer (score 19):

To apply [material design's button press animation](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B3T7oTWa3HiFSTNhRndpWXBwRDA/components-buttons-flatbuttons.webm) to any element, set the element's android background attribute to:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

In your case:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linear_tv_layout"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:paddingBottom="7px"
  android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
```

Comment: Good answer. However, if your project targets an API level that is lower that 11, you have to change the attribute to "?attr/selectableItemBackground".

Comment: Thank you. That's very useful and simple as well

Comment: how to add a custom color background and still maintain the material design animation?

Answer (score 4):

@danLeon:
 Instead of
   android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"

you should use
   android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"

former will modify the UI as well, which is not required.

Answer (score 2):

Try to bring that layout to front in code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View mainView = this.findViewById(R.id.mainView);
    this.setContentView(mainView);

    LinearLayout linear_tv_layout = (LinearLayout)mainView.findViewById(R.id.linear_tv_layout);
    linear_tv_layout.bringToFront();
    // or: mainView.bringChildToFront(linear_tv_layout);
}
```

If that does not work, check if there is one or more view overlapped over that LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a sample layout may be this can give you some idea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
  android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dip"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dip"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i tried that, now im getting error within that tab. This is what i had in my drable xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:background="#313CDD"
    />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
    android:background="#313CDD"
    />
</selector>
can you show me your btn_default xml

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is by setting this attribute: `android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"`

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linear_tv_layout"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:paddingBottom="7px"
  android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
  >
```