# Android RelativeLayout change color onClick

Tags: java, android

How do i change the color of a Relative Layout i use as a clickable on Click like the normal Button?
Like i want a visual feedback the layout was pressed.

I tried it with a selector bound to the background property like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/black" />
   <item android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```

and used it in the Layouts backround...

`android:background="@color/layout_selector"`

but this gives me an Inflate Exception...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try the following steps:

In **res --> values** folder create **color.xml** with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>     
    <color name="black">#000000</color> 
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

As `<item>` tag in selector requires a drawable attribute or child tag defining a drawable, your **layout_selector.xml** file (which is saved in **res --> drawable**) should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/black"/> 
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/black" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/> 
 </selector>
```

Also, as said earlier, the relative layout should be clickable (`android:clickable="true"`)

and its background set as `android:background="@drawable/layout_selector"`

Hope it helps

Comment: Excellent. This works like a charm. Problem in fact was it had to be a drawable resource and not in the android:color List.

Comment: @AVirvara : i have done exactly the same. When der is no focus on it .it shows white background but when i click on it, it doesn't switch it to black i don't know why? I have set all the properties. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Like GuyFawkes said, using `android:color` in the selector will give you a phat exception when you assign the selector to the layout with `android:background`

Comment: thanx a lot. after remove of android:state_enabled="false".its working fine

Comment: In my case it only worked after removing `android:state_enabled="false"`, and it also worked with and without `android:clickable="true"` in the RelativeLayout

Answer (score 10):

Use [selector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) on the android:background attribute of your RealtiveLayout.
Also make the layout clickable (through `android:clickable="true"`).

Comment: i tried as you suggested but it wont work. edited post accordingly.

Comment: Where did you put the selector file? If you put them in /drawable/ use @drawable/layout_selector

Comment: i copied the file in the drawable and used it as you suggested but still the same error... `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.views.MainView}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class <unknown>`

Comment: For unknown to me reasons, the `android:background` cannot use Color Selector - it must be Drawable Selector (it means that you should replace `android:color` tags with `android:drawable`, and put into drawables some 1x1 px black / white pngs. Not the nicest solution, but...

Comment: AFAIK, the background resorce MUST BE drawable, not the color list (check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953606/android-trouble-with-color-state-list-resources-how-to-specify-a-background-col)

Answer (score 0):

Layouts are not displayed into the screen. They only may to conrain views. You shold add some View and then add onClick listener to that view.

Possible dublicate: [Android clickable layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533320/android-clickable-layout)

Answer (score 0):

put this layout_selector.xml in drawable folder ie(res>drawable>layout_selector.xml)
then set `android:background="@drawable/layout_selector"` instead `android:background="@color/layout_selector"`