# Android, Simple box inside a button?

Tags: android, button

I want to have a button like the one in the link below. How can i achieve it just by java code or xml? By the way it's going to be of a different color when pressed. I've explored similar posts but none helped. Any help appreciated.

The button which i want

[image]

Comment: What has not helped you? Which posts did you find? Where **exactly** lies your problem? _What have you tried so far?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a `View` with large rectangle and add what you want(e.g. `Label` contains 'Number Of Students' and/or something else)  in the view.

Then, add `onClickListener` to the `View`.

To change clicked colour, refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5790946/1930006)

Comment: So seems there is no way to do so without turning from buttons to views! because i have a lot of buttons which now i must change all of them to views!

Comment: Then, why don't you create a custom view like that? That will definitely save your time and simplify your code.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm going to do so. Thanks for answering and not complaining about details XD