# How to enable the "pressed" look on LinearLayout

Tags: android, focus, android-linearlayout, android-view

I have the following UI presented when my `ListView` is empty:
[image]

Now, I want that when the user will press this "New Reminder" layout, it'll change to a "highlighted" state (with the blue focus background in ICS and the yellow color in GB)

The layout is `clickable` and the `onClick` method is called, but there is no indication for the user while he press his finger down.

I tried setting `focusable` to `true`, but it didn't do the trick.

What can I do to give any view the default "pressed" effect?

Thank you!

Comment: if somebody wants to get full solution, check this repository: https://github.com/shamanland/AndroidLayoutSelector there is custom clickable/checkable ```LinearLayout``` like a ```ToggleButton```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you correctly. If you want to create pressed state for this layout, you have to prepare state drawable xml ([more info](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)). Up there you can set what should your layout looks like while in pressed state.

Comment: I would think there will be a built-in way, like "pressable", but it's working nontheless so thank you!

Comment: Also, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4534092/1044642) from another question here on SO.

Answer (score 4):

With your layout, you can set background with drawable like below.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_big_off" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for the details, but @Seraphis answered the more "teaching" answer so I'm accepting his.

Answer (score 2):

Draw-able like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/left_radio_selected"/>
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/left_radio_inactive"/>
<item android:state_enabled="true"  android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/left_radio_selected"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/left_radio_active"/>
```

and set your `linerlayout.setSelected(true);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but your question seems a little vague. From my understanding what you want might be suggested in this post [Force a ListView item to stay "pressed" after being clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860085/force-a-listview-item-to-stay-pressed-after-being-clicked)

Comment: Definetly not. This is not a part of the ListView. It is a separate layout that I want to have a "pressed" background

Comment: Oh sorry then, glad you found an answer!