# android - ListView doesn't blink on tapping

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

What to do if a ListView stopped blinking on tapping after adding onClickListener and onClick() method for convertView in adapter?
I extended ArrayAdapter and everything was okay. Then I added this:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //some code
        }
```

onClick() worked properly (unlike setting onClickListener for whole ListView in Activity class, as I tried before, but unsuccessful), but it doesn't blink anymore when I "click". Where's the problem?

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by 'blink'?

Comment: @Arkadiy возможно, не совсем точно слово подобрал. Обычно при нажатии на ячейку она становится чуть темнее, а у меня - никакой визуальной реакции, хотя функциональность onClick() выполняется

Comment: @Arkadiy or you don't speak Russian? Sorry if I'm mistaken, I saw your name and thought you did.

Comment: Я говорю по-русски, просто не уверен, что здесь допустимо на не-английском

Comment: Отвечу на русском пока: можешь попробовать сделать background у лэйаута convertView не просто цветом/изображением, а selector
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533320/android-clickable-layout

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not use `convertView.setOnClickListener`, instead try using `listView.setOnItemClickListener` to listen to click on your rows.

I think this the reason of your problem. The reason the row "blink" is because the background is a selector drawable that has a different color for the pressed state. If you intercept the user interaction with your listener the row is never pressed.